# How to set transfer encoding when sending plain text email using System.Net.Mail

Tags: .net, smtp, smtpclient

When I send plain text emails using SmtpClient class, transfer encoding is set to quoted-printable:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

How can I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compose message using [AlternateView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.aspx):

```
 MailMessage message = new MailMessage("from@example.com", "to@example.com");
 message.Subject = "Test";
 AlternateView plainText = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("test");
 plainText.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.SevenBit;
 message.AlternateViews.Add(plainText);
 message.IsBodyHtml = false;

 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
 smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: For my purposes I needed to use the static `AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(string)` method since I had no files on disk. This doesn't eliminate the base64 encoded message. It just creates a multipart message with the plain text version too. Better than nothing, but still frustratingly stupid.